# JSF can't invoke Form reset button programmatically, or, reset Session variables

Tags: javascript, jsf, session, javabeans

Lots of time spent with other language/templating-engine combinations, however fairly new to JSF and have the "pleasure" of taking over a legacy JSF 1.1 project that uses a [basic Sun JSF lib](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-impl/1.1_02) and for political reasons can not be updated to something more modern like JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces or IceFaces, which I'd personally like to do after reading up on the capabilities of those.

The setup is a simple web app with landing page plus two tabs (Person & Address), each powered by their own Backing Beans and JSF pages. Six total navigation states as each tab starts with a "Search Form" page which leads to a "Search Results" page on submit and then a "View" page *onmousedown* (click action) of an individual result; for each of Person & Address data. The "Search Form" pages are session-scoped, and designed to pass search parameters around to each other in a header box entitled "User's Search Query". It does this because the "Search Results" page for Address searches is really an overloaded Person search result with Address thrown in for "Search for People by Address". Yes this could all probably be accomplished from a single page with some optional search params, but its not, and for whatever reason I'm not permitted to change the core page structure, just tasked to bug fix.

There's a long-standing bug I've been asked to fix, where one page (Person) always shows search parameters from the other (Address) when both are set, because of some incomplete logic (inside the panelGrid where the search query parameters are displayed):

```
<h:outputText value="Coverage Type:"/>
<h:outputText value="#{addressSearchUI.searchParameters.coverageType}" 
   rendered="#{empty personSearchUI.searchParameters.coverageType}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{personSearchUI.searchParameters.coverageType}"
   rendered="#{!empty personSearchUI.searchParameters.coverageType}"/>
```

A little too overly simplistic; if a Person search's Coverage Type was set, use that, but if not, try to use the Address coverageType search parameter. Works great when only one or the other were set.

**PROBLEM CASES:**
Since they are session scoped, what if both of them were set in separate searches and we're on the Address page? The value from the old Person search displays (and vice versa; this is the main problem). What if neither of them are set yet? It should show a default value of ALL COVERAGE, easy enough to add but doesn't address that main problem.

SOLUTION:
Thought this would be an easy fix but I've hit a major wall trying to do either one of the following two simple things that I think would solve my problem:

A) get the session-scoped value of one page's search parameter and reset it or set to empty string (then that naiive presentation logic could be left as is)

B) call the reset button of one page programmatically from Java when backing bean init() method gets called as we switch tabs (I can call the method but am not sure how to get the original session instance rather than creating a new one, which will fire to a non-existent page UI-wise)

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

A) Adding an **actionListener** attribute to the submit button itself and trying to forcibly reset values from the other Search Form.

```
<h:commandButton
       id="personReset"
       styleClass="submitButton"
       value="Reset"     
       action="#{transactionSearchUI.resetSearch}"/>

<h:commandButton 
      id="personSearch"     
      styleClass="searchButton"
      value="Search"
      rendered="#{personSearchUI.canDo['performSearch']}" 
      actionListener="#{addressSearchUI.resetSearch}"
      action="#{personSearchUI.performSearch}"/>
```

B) In the backing bean of each search, try to invoke the reset button of the other:

```
/* utility method */
  private UIComponent findComponent(String id, UIComponent where) {
       if (where == null) {
          return null;
       }
       else if (where.getId().equals(id)) {
          return where;
       }
       else {
          List<UIComponent> childrenList = where.getChildren();
          if (childrenList == null || childrenList.isEmpty()) {
             return null;
          }
          for (UIComponent child : childrenList) {
             UIComponent result = null;
             result = findComponent(id, child);
             if(result != null) {
                return result;
             }
          }
        return null;
      }
  }

//... then inside init() method that is called when Person tab loads

FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot root = facesContext.getViewRoot();      
HtmlCommandButton button = (HtmlCommandButton) findComponent("addressReset", root);
ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent(button);
actionEvent.queue();
```

Fails with NullPointerException, so clearly can't access one tab from the other's backing bean in this way (unless I'm missing something).

C) JavaScript approach to reset values from one tab to the other:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearAddressSearchParams() {
    document.getElementById('AddressSearch:addressSearch:addressReset').click();
    document.forms['AddressSearch:addressSearch'].reset();
    return false;
}
window.onload = clearStats;
</script>
```

Neither of those client-side methods of trying to fire the "Reset" button action are going to work, since again, the "Person" and "Address" Search Forms were setup as two totally separate beans and pages (even though one ultimately extends the other), one won't be active (or available in the DOM) so it won't find the elements.

At this point, I know there is clearly a simpler solution, but I'm at my wits end and probably coming at this from the wrong angle, so I don't know what else to do but put up a bounty for some of the JSF geniuses here. But if anyone can suggest a fix (given my limitations of older JSF technology, no adding external libs and maintaining same basic code structure), you'll get the bounty and tons of appreciation.

EDIT: To summarize all this into a single question, can anyone suggest a reliable (legacy-JSF 1.1 compatible) way to flush a session variable or reset it, independently of its page where it gets set being active?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Tomahawk? The `<t:saveState>` would save your soul. This basically simulates the JSF 2.0 view scope. So every view would have its own state instead of a session wide shared state.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the old Sun JSF lib is part of a common library that many other apps depend on, and we're forced to build against it for now. We're making a major upgrade early 2015 though and I finally get some say in that...

Comment: Yes, I know I should share the code and ask a helpful question to get a helpful solution... however I can't legally do that without redacting which was already done (in case you didn't guess what with the vagueness and such). It will take me some time to pull it all out into a runnable/isolated MVCE as you mentioned. I'll try to do that in the next day or so though before the bounty expires... 

In the interim, if you or anyone knows about tried and true Session clearing methods built into JSF by the 1.1 spec, it may be a quicker solution. Surely there's a way to say Session.values.clear(); ?

Comment: Something like JSF's equivalent of JSP's session.invalidate() but possibly specific variable-wise, or, PHP's session_unset() ?

In our case, it's perfectly fine if all values are lost between separate searches. Everything could be cleared short of login I suppose...

Comment: I just read your last EDIT question. :-) Once I had a similar security requirement and the approach was to do not load the data in a variable at all, but instead, load it per request basis. This means mapping the data access to a RequestScoped MB and use a f:param. You will be buying data access security in cost of CPU and I/O. Also you need to implement a filter to disable browser cache and use https.